# DOTween: How to make a spring bounce effect?

Tags: unity, animation, tweening, dotween

I am looking how to make a bouncing effect with DOTween, like when the object is attached to a spring. How can I make an effect like this?

Answer (score 4):

As it was not clear to me in the documentation I am exposing the answer here:

You can use

```
DOShakePosition(float duration, float/Vector3 strength, int vibrato, float randomness, bool snapping, bool fadeOut)
```

> Shakes a Transform's localPosition with the given values.

This configuration worked for me:

```
transform.DOShakePosition(2.0f, strength: new Vector3(0, 2, 0), vibrato: 5, randomness: 1, snapping: false, fadeOut: true);
```

Result:

[image]